# How does certificate authority initially authenticate public keys?

Tags: authentication, encryption, public-key-encryption, client-certificates, digital-certificate

So when initially a client wishes to register his public key to a CA, he will need the public key of the CA, in order to send his own public key to the CA for registration. How does the client get the key?

And eventually when the client does manage to send his public key for registration, can a Man in the Middle attack not masquarade himself as the client and send his own public key instead of the clients?

I have a basic idea of how CAs work but do not understand how the initial registration of public keys can happen without any sniffing or spoofing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "registering a public key".  So I think you may be talking about the [CSR process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I'm not familiar with the terms but from what I gatherd from the wikipedia page, this is exactly what I mean. Can a Man in the Middle Attack not happen during this procedure?

Answer (score 1):

A Certification (or Certificate) Signing Request is signed by the requestor's private key. This prevents MITM tampering, but not MITM tamper + replace public key + re-sign.

The mitigating factor is that the request is usually then transmitted over TLS, providing tamper-proof delivery of the payload (and gives the sender a way of validating that the CA is the expected CA).

The TLS server auth certificate will eventually chain up to a certificate which was built into the OS / browser / other-client-trust-list.